# Java import/export dependencies

Tags: java, import, export

I'm trying to find a way to list the (static) dependency requirements of a jar file, in terms of which symbols are required at run time.

I can see that the methods exported by classes can be listed using "javap", but there doesn't seem to be an opposite facility to list the 'imports'. Is it possible to do this?

This would be similar to the dumpbin utility in Windows development which can be used to list the exports and imports of a DLL.

EDIT : Thanks for the responses; I checked out all of the suggestions; accepted DependencyFinder as it most closely meets what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Outbound dependencies](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#ShowingOnlyOutboundDependencies) feature of [DependencyFinder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/). You can do that entirely in the GUI, or in command line exporting XML.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get that information using [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer) that will give you the dependencies between the jars in a directory. It'll also give you a list of dependencies that don't exist in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a public jar (as in, not yours) then it might be in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/).